# Double google analytics code at single page may increase page views?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I added two different type of google analytics codes to my site. First:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-00000000-1"]);
            _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
            (function () {
                var ga = document.createElement("script"); ga.type = "text/javascript"; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
</script>
```

Second:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
            m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

when I added these two codes to my site that time my bounce rate is very low, last 30 minutes page view is very high  and final report is more page views per day. If i removed these two codes and i added new tracking code means bounce rate is very high, last 30 minutes page view is very low and over all page view also very low. What is happening.? Please help me guys.

Comment: The first (ga.js) is classic google analytics second is universal analytics(analytics.js)   Adding them both to the site is going to give you double hits.  because they are both trying to inserting data.   Classic analytics had a different way of recording data universal analytics should be more accurate and give you additional information that classic doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

Pageview are tracked double if you use the the tracking id (the number that starts with "UA-") for both code versions.

Re. your comment "I couldn't understand the difference between these two codes":

The first set of code is an outdated version of the tracking code. You should not use this anymore, especially since it does not support all current featues of Google Analytics (and will not support features that might be added to GA in the future).

The second set of the is the current version (also called "Universal Analytics), you should use that exclusively.  If you still need m[ultiple trackers you need to use named trackers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers#working_with_multiple_trackers) if you want to configure them independently (if you use the same tracking id you will still get double pageviews).

So, use the second version of the code, drop the first one and you should be fine.

Comment: Its not even possible to create a classic analytics account anymore on the website.  To my knowledge all accounts were upgraded to universal analytics.   It wouldn't surprise me if using the classic code would result in strange data.  what do you think @eike?

Comment: @DaImTo, I actually work with clients who still run the old code. It still seems to work (actually the biggest problem is when different parts of the website run different versions of the code, since this pretty much obliterates cross-domain tracking). However I am pretty sure that at the processing stage it is all Universal Analytics, plus I couldn't even imagine why somebody would _want_ to run that clunker.  Personally I was really happy when Google introduced Universal Analytics and the measurement protocol.

Comment: "old clunker" very descriptive and I hole hardly agree.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thanks for your info. Finally i tested my site, if i use these two codes two times page view is recording. I don't know why google allow this. Its a major bug from google.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want a pageview twice? That definitly will break google reports because you send useless data.

- Pageviews will double (every page is viewed twice).
- Bounce rates will decrease drastically (a bounce means a visitor only sees one page = has one pageview and then leaves - but your visitors will have 2 pagesviews, so no bounces)

So only have a tracking code once.

Comment: Actually there are two type of codes. My intention is not to double the page view. I couldn't understand the difference between these two codes. My doubt is is this correct code or not.?

Comment: See the answer from Eike. There are two page view codes.